# VBA dynamic range inserting current month's name

Tags: excel, vba, range

I'm super noob with Excel, and have been doing most of my macro stuff via the recorder. However now I'm stuck.

I want to have a dynamic range that goes in the Z column cell $Z$7 to the cell one up from the last numeric entry in that Z column (as the bottom cell is a total, and has different formula from the cells above that I want to be in the dynamic range).

Here's what I've got recorded from the macro recorder, now I need to tweak it.

```
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="monthlyclaim", RefersToR1C1:= _
"='February 2015'!R7C26:R567C26"
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="yearlyclaim", RefersToR1C1:= _
"='February 2015'!R7C29:R567C29"
```

Any suggestions? Also it says February 2015 in code but what would actually be better would to have it for the active sheet..as will be running this macro on a monthly basis. Would I be able to just substitute in ActiveSheet for 'February 2015' in the code? It's not working for me so far.

Let me know if you need  more information to go by.

Comment: Reserch how to get the last row in a range, that'll give you a good start.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="monthlyclaim", RefersToR1C1:= "='February 2015'!R7C26:R" & sheets("February 2015").cells(rows.Count,26).end(xlup).row - 1 & "C26"
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="yearlyclaim", RefersToR1C1:= "='February 2015'!R7C29:R" & sheets("February 2015").cells(rows.Count,29).end(xlup).row - 1 & "C29"
```

Comment: That will work too, but my version will dynamically grow if your items grow without needing to redefine the name :)

Comment: You need to put -1 after .row in each line of mine to cater for the total column. I have updated the original answer

Answer (score 0):

Hi, you can use "offset" combined with counta to give dynamic number of rows:

```
RefersToR1C1:= "=Offset('February 2015!R7C26,0,0,counta('February 2015!R7C26:R10000C26) - 1,1)"
```

As for the names per sheet thing... I can't say I really use "worksheet" scoped names, they seem to give me a headache... but try something like this: i.e. instead of adding name from the workbook object, add from the worksheet:

```
for each wsSheet in thisworkbook.sheets
    wsSheet.names.add Name:="monthlyclaim", RefersToR1C1:= "=Offset('" & wssheet.name & "'!R7C26,0,0,counta('" & wssheet.name & "'!R7C26:R10000C26) - 1,1)"
next
```

Rinse and repeat for other name... So kinda conceptually different but same effect: any formulas on those sheets that reference "monthlyclaim" will match a worksheet scoped name first.

Comment: Won't this give the wrong answer if there is a blank cell in the list?

Comment: true... Dan's answer below might be more suitable in that case (if there are blanks)

Comment: I was thinking that if they were all numbers you could use MATCH(9.999999999999999999E+307,Z7:Z26) to get the row of the total instead of counting entries.

Comment: or if there's a total row there's probably some text "Total:" or something somewhere you can search for or match on

Answer (score 0):

Cool that worked awesome!

Now the hard part..heres my code

Sub newSheet()
    '
    ' NewSheet Macro
    '
    ' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+e
    '

```
'current counts

ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="hydrocount", RefersTo:="='" & ActiveSheet.Name & "'!$AE$7:$AE$" & ActiveSheet.Range("AC" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 1
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-23]=""Isaac"",1,0)"
Range("AE7").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("hydrocount"), Type:=xlFillDefault

Dim wks As Worksheet


If MsgBox("Is month complete?", vbYesNo, "Confirm Action") = vbYes Then
'When user selects Yes
Range("A1").Select
Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
Selection.Copy

Set wks = Sheets.Add(after:=ActiveSheet)

Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False


Month_year_picker.Show
'wks.Name = InputBox("What is the new month? Must be entered in the format of 'Month Year' - e.g. April 2015", "Sheet Name")

wks.Name = wks_Name


ActiveSheet.Paste

Else
'When user selects No
Exit Sub
End If

'
' RecalculateAnyNewMonth Macro
'
'claims stuff beginning

ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="monthlyclaim", RefersTo:="='" & ActiveSheet.Name & "'!$Z$7:$Z$" &         ActiveSheet.Range("Z" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 1

ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="yearlyclaim", RefersTo:="='" & ActiveSheet.Name & "'!$AC$7:$AC$" & ActiveSheet.Range("AC" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 1

'claims stuff finish

'countsnew

ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="hydrocountnew", RefersTo:="='" & ActiveSheet.Name & "'!$AE$7:$AE$" & ActiveSheet.Range("AC" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 1


'The strPrevMonth string works based on the name of the sheet, if the sheet name is "January 2015",
'the string will be "December 2014".
'If the sheet name is "May 2015", the string will be "April 2015" and so on.
strPrevMonth = Format(DateAdd("M", -1, ActiveSheet.Name), "MMMM YYYY")

strMyFormula = "=IF(RC[-18]=""Isaac"",R6C8,0)+IF(RC[-12]=""BF"",R6C14,0)+IF(RC[-11]=""Client"",R6C15,0)+(IF(RC[-8]=""S"",1,0)*(IF(RC[-9]=""A"",R2C17,0)+IF(RC[-9]=""C"",R3C17,0)+IF(RC[-9]=""CS"",R4C17,0)))+IF(RC[-5]=""Y"",R6C21,0)+IF(RC[-4]=""Y"",R6C22,0)+((R6C24*RC[-2])*IF(RC[-2]="""",0,1))-'" & strPrevMonth & "'!RC[3]"

strMyFormula2 = "=RC[-3]+'" & strPrevMonth & "'!RC"


Range("Z7").FormulaR1C1 = strMyFormula
Range("Z7").AutoFill Destination:=Range("monthlyclaim")


Range("AC7").FormulaR1C1 = strMyFormula2
Range("AC7").AutoFill Destination:=Range("yearlyclaim")

'counts

ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="hydrocountnew", RefersTo:="='" & ActiveSheet.Name & "'!$AE$7:$AE$" & ActiveSheet.Range("AC" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 1
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-23]=""Isaac"",1,0)"
Range("AE7").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("hydrocountnew"), Type:=xlFillDefault

Range("G573").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(hydrocountnew)-SUM(hydrocount)"
Range("G574").Select


End Sub
```

Unfortunately they way it currently is going the sum Hydrocountnew - sum Hydrocount gives the right values at the time, but once the macro is run again (for the new month) it resets across all sheet, updating to the most recent one.

Any ideas on how to get around this? I want it to run the calculation instantaneously, but then whatever has been calculated for that slot get stored in its appropriate sheet and not overwritten when the macro runs again.